# KOHA ILS (Integrated Library System) Installation in Windows 7 64 Bit

Tags: windows, open-source, installation

I need to install [KOHA ILS](http://koha.org) in Windows 7 but it turns out it can only be installed on Ubuntu.

Can anyone give me some guide, on how to install it on Windows 7? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Koha can run on any Linux based system. It is easiest to install and use on Debian or Ubuntu as the packages available make it very easy to install - manually installing can be difficult and time consuming.

Ubuntu instructions are here:
http://wiki.koha-community.org/wiki/Koha_on_ubuntu_-_packages

You can install it on Windows (or a Mac or a Linux desktop) using VirtualBox software (virtualbox.org) - you need to install VirtualBox, then install either Debian or Ubuntu server as a virtual machine, then you can install Koha. This is not recommended for production use, more for trying it out and experimenting.

If you have minimal or no experience in administering Linux systems then you have a steep learning curve ahead of you...

If you would just like to try Koha out look at one of the demos:
http://koha-community.org/demo/

While it can be daunting gettng Koha installed, once you are there then you have a fully-featured integrated library management system to meet the needs of your library, and a great worldwide community.